# Using version Python 3.7.4 and still getting syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, f-string

**I'm getting a syntax error on my f-string statements even though i'm using python version 3.7.4**

```
 my_name= "raushan"
 print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}")

File "<ipython-input-5-0b1a3af6fa22>", line 2
    print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

python version i'm using.

```
!python --version

Python 3.7.4
```

Comment: What gives (after `import sys`) `print sys.version`?

Comment: Did you executed the program with `python3 program.py`?

Comment: @SergeBallesta
3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @SergeBallesta 
Why do they show different versions? f-strings were only implemented on versions 3.6 and later yes?

Comment: It looks like you are using ipython. It uses its own version of Python (here 3.5.6) while your path uses a 3.7.4 version. Having multiple versions of Python is normally not a problem provided you are aware of it and know which tool uses which version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll do it here.
I believe that your error is that in line 2 before the print statement, you added an unnecessary space (indent).
Python doesn't like unnecessary indents.

Does this work for you?

```
my_name= "raushan"
print(f"Let's talk about {my_name}")
```

Edit: 
Apparently both the lines have unnecessary indents.